# TCP : recv() getting ECONNRESET

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to implement a simple client/server program on linux using TCP
and the standard socket.h library. server handling multiple clients and each client can close() or shutdown() the socket any time he wants.

on the server side (using a non blocking read):

```
int nBytes;
if ((nBytes = recv(socket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, MSG_DONTWAIT)) == -1)
{
    if (errno != EAGAIN && errno != EWOULDBLOCK)
    {
        //print to log
    }

}
if (nBytes == 0)
{

    //other side closed the connection
}
```

I'm getting recv() returning -1 and error set to ECONNRESET. If the client has closed the connection shouldn't recv() return 0?

Comment: tcpdump will tell you whats actually happening

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are numerous causes, including but not limited to:

- the peer deliberately reset the connection
- the peer closed the connection while he still had unread data pending
- you had sent data to a connection that had already been closed by the peer
- you had pending write data and the TCP retries have timed out
- TCP keepalive detected a lost connection.

This is a fatal error, and you should close the socket when you get it.

> each client can `close()` or `shutdown()` the socket any time he wants.

No he can't. See above.

Comment: I wonder why this critical fatal error isn't mentioned in the recv man

Comment: @susdu This error condition is mentioned in the official X/Open documentation at <http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm>: The recv() function shall fail if: ... [ECONNRESET]
A connection was forcibly closed by a peer.

Comment: @susdu 'Additional erros may be generated by the protocol layers ...'

Answer (score 4):

If the remote peer has cleanly closed the connection, and there are no more bytes waiting to be read on the local end, then yes, `recv()` should return `0`.  So if you get an `ECONNRESET` then it's reasonable to assume that an orderly closure is not what has happened.

An `ECONNRESET` often indicates that the remote peer sent a RST packet without having first closed the connection cleanly.  There are many reasons why this might happen.  Alternatively, as EJP observed, a reset may originate locally, too.

In any event, after an `ECONNRESET` it's not reasonable to suppose that you will be able to read anything further from the socket, so in your particular case you should probably handle it much the same as way as you handle `recv()` returning `0`, +/- logging.

Comment: The reset can originate at your end as well as the peer.

Comment: You should handle it as a fatal error on the connection, not indistinguishably from a clean disconnect.

Comment: @EJP, by "you" I meant the OP, for his particular program as he described it, not the generic "you".  I have clarified.

Comment: By 'you' I mean everybody.

Answer (score 3):

You may get ECONNRESET if client closed his side without reading sent data. If he closed connection properly you'll get 0.

Comment: You *will* get it under that circumstance, but there are others.