# How do I add shutdown() to socket.socket() context manager?

Tags: python, sockets, contextmanager

`socket.socket()` creates a socket as a context manager, but it only calls `close()` on exit processing. I want to add `sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)` to it because if it has unread data pending, calling `close()` **only** will cause the peer to get `ECONNRESET` (which caused me several hours to figure it out), as explained here [TCP : recv() getting ECONNRESET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093071/tcp-recv-getting-econnreset) (also refer to [socket.shutdown vs socket.close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409783/socket-shutdown-vs-socket-close))

How do I do that?

BTW, is this a good idea(as I haven't seen others do this)?